# Setting currentTime on <audio> element crashes Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have found that programmatically setting the `currentTime` attribute on an HTML5 `<audio>` element crashes Firefox 43 (actually killing the whole browser, not just producing a JS error)

My JavaScript code is shown below:

```
// 'offset' variable set to valid numeric value elsewhere
audio.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    audio.currentTime = offset;
});
audio.play();
```

The same code works fine in latest Chrome (47.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were 2 issues with my code. To prevent the browser crashing I needed to remove the `autoplay` attribute which I had put on the `<audio>` element and then forgotten about:

```
<audio id="player" autoplay></audio>
```

After I did this the browser no longer crashed completely, but the audio playback was glitchy and skipped around very quickly.

This second issue was resolved after I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162472/setting-currenttime-attribute-programatically-on-audio-element-causes-event-list) and removed the event handler after setting the currentTime (turns out setting `currentTime` causes the `canplay` event to fire again creating an infinite event loop - but only on Firefox not Chrome for some reason).

My final code, working on both Firefox and Chrome looks like this:

```
function onCanPlay(){
    audio.currentTime = offset;
    audio.oncanplay = null;
}
audio.oncanplay = onCanPlay;
```

Comment: @Gothdo because the code is simpler and I only ever need 1 listener for that event, using addEventListener would also work fine though